# Unknown File System, after delete Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, boot-failure, grubrescue

I deleted the partition which contains the Ubuntu 12.0.4 OS. I have Windows in another partition *(dual boot)*. When I reboot the system, it shows me the following.

```
unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

I read the previous questions about this topic and I tried to install Ubuntu again using USB flash drive but was unable to boot from this device. I do not have a the Ubuntu LiveCD.

What should I do now to boot from windows?

Comment: Your answer is [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/62483). Your question is an *exact duplicate* of [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/62483).

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a Fresh USB stick with Ubuntu live in it. use [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) Software for it

Boot with that stick.

Install Boot Repair program from internet on to the pen-drive and run the program.

Run the Program and fix MBR record

Detailed Steps to use, here : [Using Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)